# Wrong catch block running

Tags: java, error-handling

In my method, pseudo-code below, on a line where two exceptions are created (ArrayIndexOutOfBounds and NumberFormatException) in one line.

On this line the input file changes from X+Y columns to X columns.

The outer catch is caught first and stops the program before the inner catch can do that itself.

I need the inner loop to catch the exception as I'm using that to print out the data to a file.

```
try{
    Initialize local variables
    //Includes getting numerical strings from input fields
    //Hence NumberFormatException to check for correct input
    try{
        get file name
        //hence FileNotFoundException
        try{
            read line, get column A, B and C 
            //Column B is at an index larger than X
            //hence ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
        }catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException){
            print data to file
        }
    } catch(FileNotFoundException){
        error message
    }
} catch(NumberFormatException){
    error message
    //error caught here, checks for whether
    //numbers were entered in the required fields
}
```

Is there a way to force the inner catch to trigger first or does the code need reworking around this?

Comment: How getting the file name causes `NumberFormatException`?

Comment: Oh blast, I thought I could simplify this to its bare bones but I't confusing the answer. I'll edit the question.

Comment: the exception may be thrown in outer try-catch block. print the stacktrace of the exception in out catch block to get the extact line number where the exception occurs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try catching a more general Exception in the inner block.
If the caught exception is instanceof NumberFormatException, pass it on to the outer block or return the error message right there.

Comment: The exception is correct. Between the last line of the code running without exceptions and the line that generates exceptions, the number of columns (Parsed CSV) reduces so that B is guaranteed to be larger than the array's length.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that The csv file that was being read had additional commas to stop the file being jagged; the idea that I was relying on to print to file.

The exception was correct for the expected input but now I'm catching `NumberFormatException`  and `IndexOutOfBoundsException` within the inntermost catch with a multicatch for this additional possibility.